# my createElement(div) is not appearing on my screen, is there something wrong in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript

```
base = document.createElement('div');
base.style.width = '200px';
base.style.height = '250px';
base.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
base.style.color = 'white';
base.style.opacity = '0.5';
```

It doesnt show a black 200px by 250px div on the screen when I run the code. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You may need to append it to… somewhere! The body, a div etc

Comment: I completely forgot about that!

Comment: document.body.append(base);

Comment: You are creating the element. It exists, but only in the javascript realm - for now. To see it in the page, you need to insert it into the page.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild